Manga related to a white hair girl who is the empress's half-sister
The female lead had white hair and was working as a maid. The male lead had black hair and his half blood sister was a bully. They brought
the female lead to take the punishment while tutoring instead of the male lead's sister. The male lead got the female lead pregnant and she run away and turn out to be the empress's half blood sister.

Are there any fantasy or science fiction aspects? We kind of need something to be under the purview of the site. You can [edit] the details in.

Thank you for the edit, but [tag:fantasy-genre] is for discussions of the genre, not to tag things as fantasy. And, what does make it fantasy? Monsters? Magic? Prophecy? Gods? Isekai/reincarnation?

If it's The Maid No Longer Desires her Master, then it wouldn't be on topic, any more than The Princess Diaries or Roman Holiday would be.

I’m voting to close this question because there are no identified fantasy/sci-fi aspects.

Could this be The Maid No Longer Desires her Master?

Lynn has never had an easy life. A beautiful girl with pale silver hair resembling that of the Empire’s princess, she is sold to work in the Dukedom of Ereuputh. Elizabeth, the duke’s daughter, harbors jealousy towards the princess and takes pleasure in causing Lynn to suffer. Despite enduring in silence, Lynn’s life takes a turn when Martin, the young master of the dukedom, returns. He shows her kindness and she falls for him, knowing that it will only lead to heartbreak. Unable to resist, Lynn shares a passionate night with him, unaware that Martin is not the kind boy she used to know. For he’s had a taste of her, and he will never let her go…



Is it on-topic?  Nothing in the synopsis says "on-topic."

@DavidW - I'm a few episodes in. It's set in a fictional Renaissance period kingdom. There's a monarchy and a feudal system, complete with lords, ladies and knights. So far it seems an entirely mundane place. No overt magic or fantasy elements.

Interesting..around episode 10 the author seems to have decided that they want it to be set in the Enlightenment instead. People start showing up with guns and fob-watches and the architecture becomes far more modern European. Still nothing fantastical

By episode 25, the young master is clay-shooting with a shotgun and walking around in tweeds. The anachronism in this story is actually painful to behold.
